# Rounding problems in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point-precision

I've got a problem with rounding in JavaScript. I'm using a function for rounding:

```
function roundup(rnum, rlength){
    var newnumber = Math.round(rnum * Math.pow(10, rlength)) / Math.pow(10, rlength);
    return newnumber;
}

var amount = roundup(2253.825, 3);
```

Strange thing is, when I round up the number `2253.825`, the result is `2253.82` which has to be `2253.83`. When I round up the number `5592.825` the result is `5592.83`, which is correct.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Related: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999#comic :)

Comment: @Grimbode, take a look at my fiddle. I added a value 2020.825 and that is working correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/poqnnxyo/2/

Comment: Question: Are you trying to round _up_, or just round? If you want to round up, then switching to `Math.ceil` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point rounding errors are at fault here. `2620.825 * 100` is `262082.49999999997`, so when you round it, the result is `262082`.

Here is a more robust approach that corrects for this:

```js
function roundup(rnum, rlength) {
    var shifted = rnum * Math.pow(10, rlength),
        rounded = Math.round(shifted),
        delta = Math.abs(shifted - rounded);

    if (delta > 0.4999999 && delta < 0.5) {
        rounded += (rounded < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    }

    return rounded / Math.pow(10, rlength);
}

console.log("2620.825 :=> " + roundup(2620.825, 2));
console.log("2621.825 :=> " + roundup(2621.825, 2));
console.log("2620.8255 :=> " + roundup(2620.8255, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem shows up inherently because the way IEEE 754 doubles work. If you really want to always get mathematically correct results, you need to use a custom datatype, for example a BigDecimal implementation like [this one](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js).

Please also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/2102532), as it may be useful.